# Prevent Python from storing inputs during loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm running a program that has a time delay if the entered password is incorrect. The problem is that if a user presses enter during the countdown in the for loop. That key press gets saved. So if the user presses enter multiple times the loop will just restart without an opportunity to enter a new password. Is there a way to catch these key presses inside the for loop and discard them?

```
while True:
    password = str(raw_input('Password:  '))
    if password != RIGHT_PASSWORD:
        for i in range(60, 0, -1):
            try:
                sys.stdout.write("\rWaiting {:3} seconds until trying again\r".format(i, end=" "))
                sys.stdout.flush()
                time.sleep(1)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                quit = raw_input("Cannot bypass wait period. Press enter to continue...")
                if quit == quit_code:
                    break
```

I can get around a number of cases by adding

```
if not password:
     continue
```

but that doesn't prevent cases like "acdasfas *return*"

Comment: Can you put `sys.stdin.flush()` just before you get the `raw_input`?

Comment: That doesn't seem to actually clear it. The closest I've gotten is     sys.stdin.readlines() which does clear the stdin but it hangs until ctrl+c which isn't the behavior I want